# Inno-Setup: "Compile Aborted" when path exceeds 260 characters in Windows Enterprise 2015 LTSB

Tags: inno-setup

Iam using Inno setup compliler 5.5.9. When the path length exceeds 260 characters "system cannot find the path specified " error is shown and compile is aborted. I tried prefixing the path with **\\?\** , and also changed the registry value for LongPathsEnabled as 1 , neither of them worked out

Comment: I have gone through it and does not work out...

Comment: Then you have to show us what did you try exactly! *"Does not work"* is useless problem description.

Comment: Edit your question, do not provide important information in comments.